# LINQ using dictionary object with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I am use Dictionary object in my LINQ Group By Clause.

It works fine as long as i don't have duplicate **Item Name** in the result.

However, it is failing when **GroupBy** query encounter with duplicate Item Name.

I am not sure whether i am using Dictionary object in my GroupBy clause correctly or not? Please advise.

**This is my model**

```
public class Item
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, float?> ItemCost { get; set; }
    public float? Cost{ get; set; }
    public float? TotalCost{ get; set; }
}
```

**Following is my selection query (LINQ) along with GroupBy**

```
        var result = myFilteredQuery
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ItemName = x.Item.Name,
                Cost= x.Item.Cost,
                CustomerName = x.Item.Customer.Name,

            }).ToList();
```

Following is my GroupBy query.

```
            return result .GroupBy(x => new { x.CustomerName})
          .Select(x => new CostByItem
          {
              CustomerName = x.Key.CustomerName,
              LineItem = x.ToDictionary(y => y.ItemName, y => y.Cost),
              TotalCost= x.Sum(y => y.Cost)
          }).ToList();
```

**p.s.** I am trying to send create data structure Group By Customer and than under each customer dictionary object Item Cost (Item Name, Item Cost) and total cost for that customer.

Comment: Failing as in? Any error message you are getting? Please be specific.

Comment: I am getting this error "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: That's obvious! You are grouping by `CustomerName` and not by `ItemName` so if there are any duplicates of ItemName under any customer you'll get that error.

Comment: Even i grouped it with ItemName , i am getting the same error. Because ItemName can be repeated in my list.  e.g. selection query result data is : {ItemName:  "test1" Cost: 123 CustomerName: Andy}{ItemName:  "test1" Cost: 234 CustomerName: Andy}{ItemName:  "test1" Cost: 444 CustomerName: Andy}

Comment: You need something unique for key of dictionary. You can combine itemName and Cost like `x.ToDictionary(y => y.ItemName + "_" + y.Cost, y => y.Cost)`.

Comment: @user1874957 - If you can have multiple ItemName for each customer then you either need to fetch just 1 item or else you can't add it a dictionary.

Comment: I am showing on UI so altering key will solve this issue but will create incorrect data on UI for key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to group the items by customer, and then group the items by name under that.  You need to use `GroupBy` **twice**.

```
result.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerName)
      .Select(x => new CostByItem
      {
          CustomerName = x.Key,
          LineItem = x.GroupBy(y => y.ItemName)
                      .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Sum(z => z.Cost)),
          TotalCost = x.Sum(y => y.Cost)
      }).ToList();
```

Also note that there's no need to use `x => new { x.CustomerName}`.  Grouping by the string value is sufficient - creating an anonymous type is unnecessary.